# How to swap keys with values in array?

Tags: php, arrays, key, swap

I have array like:

```
array(
  0 => 'a',
  1 => 'b',
  2 => 'c'
);
```

I need to convert it to:

```
array(
  'a',
  'b',
  'c'
);
```

What's the fastest way to swap keys with values?

Comment: array_flip maybe? It does exactly what you **said**, not what you want (because what you want is not really meaningful).

Comment: Use [array_flip](http://blog.jterminal.com/2014/07/use-php-array_flip-function-to-exchange-keys-and-associated-values-in-an-array.html) to swap keys with values.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

PHP has the [`array_flip`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-flip.php) function which exchanges all keys with their corresponding values, but you do not need it in your case because the arrays are the same.

```
array(
  'a',
  'b',
  'c'
);
```

This array has the keys 0, 1, and 2.

Answer (score 4):

Use `array_flip()`. That will do to swap keys with values. However, your array is OK the way it is. That is, you don't need to swap them, because then your array will become:

```
array(
  'a' => 0,
  'b' => 1,
  'c' => 2
);
```

not

```
array(
  'a',
  'b',
  'c'
);
```

Answer (score 4):

```
array(
  0 => 'a',
  1 => 'b',
  2 => 'c'
);
```

and

```
array(
  'a',
  'b',
  'c'
);
```

are the same array, the second form has 0,1,2 as implicit keys. If your array does not have numeric keys you can use [array_values](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php) function to get an array which has only the values (with numeric implicit keys).

Otherwise if you need to swap keys with values [array_flip](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-flip.php) is the solution, but from your example is not clear what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 3):

See: [array_flip](http://php.net/manual/function.array-flip.php)

Answer (score 2):

`$flipped_arr = array_flip($arr);` will do that for you.

(source: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-flip.php)

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to use [`array_flip()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-flip.php) for that.