# Alter keys and values in array php

Tags: php, arrays, function, output

I have an array.

```
Array
(
    [0] => min_order_level="5"
    [1] => max_order_level="10"
    [2] => step_order_level="4"
    [3] => product_box="9"
)
```

What I need is

```
Array
(
    [min_order_level] => "5"
    [max_order_level] => "10"
    [step_order_level] => "4"
    [product_box] => "9"
)
```

I have an idea of doing this using `foreach`. But without `foreach` is there any way to do this.

Thanks!

Comment: You can use [array_flip()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-flip.php)  [read this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6845037/how-to-swap-keys-with-values-in-array)

Comment: No, you can't, because the current values also include the `=` and the number. The OP wants to use the string part as the key and the number (with the quotes) after that as the value.

Comment: Do you need number value like `5` or string value `"5"`(with qoutas)?

Comment: I need number value like `5` which is integer.

Answer (score 5):

A simple `foreach` will do..

```
foreach($arr as $v)
{
    list($a,$b)= explode('=',$v);
    $new_arr[$a]=(int)trim($b,'"');
}
print_r($new_arr);
```

<kbd>[Working Demo](https://eval.in/143587)</kbd>

---

#### Without a `foreach` as requested on the question..

```
$new_arr = array();
array_map(function ($v) use (&$new_arr) { list($a,$b)= explode('=',$v); $new_arr[$a]=(int)trim($b,'"'); },$arr);
print_r($new_arr);
```

<kbd>[Working Demo](https://eval.in/143589)</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

One line without foreach

```
$array = [
    0 => 'min_order_level="5"',
    1 => 'max_order_level="10"',
    2 => 'step_order_level="4"',
    3 => 'product_box="9"'];

parse_str(implode('&', $array), $result);
var_dump($result);
```

---

```
array(4) {
  'min_order_level' =>
  string(3) ""5""
  'max_order_level' =>
  string(4) ""10""
  'step_order_level' =>
  string(3) ""4""
  'product_box' =>
  string(3) ""9""
}
```

---

Variant with preg_match_all

```
$string = implode("\n", $array);
preg_match_all('/(.*)="(.*)"/', $string, $matches);
$result = array_combine($matches[1], $matches[2]);
var_dump($result);
```

Answer (score 1):

The simple `foreach()` mentioned in one of the answer should be enough, however, if you want to use array functions, you can do:

```
$new = array_combine(
        array_map(function($k){  $ex=explode('=',$k); return $ex[0]; }, $arr)
        ,
        array_map(function($v){  $ex=explode('=',$v); return $ex[1]; }, $arr)
);
```

The key point here is to break the string at `=` using [explode()](http://www.php.net/explode), pass *all* the keys and values separately using [array_map()](http://www.php.net/array_map) and combine them using [array_combine().](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php)

**[DEMO](https://eval.in/143584)**

Answer (score 0):

To do it without foreach, how about array_walk

```
$new_array = array();

array_walk($array, 'callback');

function callback($item2, $key)
{
    global $new_array;
    $parts = explode('=',$item2);
    $new_array[$parts[0]]=$parts[1];    
}

print_r($new_array);
```